# Hover effect is not working: Div color is not changed when hovering over a <a> anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the div color by hovering over an anchor tag but when I am but nothing is happening, here is my code below and jsfiddel link https://jsfiddle.net/rhulkashyap/udvzanqz/.

**HTML** & **CSS**

```css
.hover-me{
  margin-bottom:50px;
  display:block;
}
.change{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#00ACC1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
}

.hover-me:hover .change{
  background:#00796B;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hover-me">Change Div color by hovering me</a>

<div class="change">Hello Universe</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`sibling selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```css
.hover-me{
  margin-bottom:50px;
  display:block;
}
.change{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#00ACC1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
}

.hover-me:hover ~ .change{
  background:#00796B;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hover-me">Change Div color by hovering me</a>
<div class="change">Hello Universe</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working perfectly however you want:

```
.hover-me:hover + .change{
      background:#00796B;
    }
```

here is working jsFiddle demo : https://jsfiddle.net/udvzanqz/2/

Answer (score 1):

Just change your css as following :-

```
.hover-me:hover+.change{
    background:#00796B;
}
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.hover-me:hover ~ .change{
  background:#00796B;
}
```